# Generate transforms only working on default install (multi-site)

Tags: image-transforms, multi-site, s3, amazon

I have a multi-site setup running within Craft 3. Everything seems to be working nicely, except for image transforms. For example:

The following transform on the default site works correctly:

```
https://www.default-site.com/index.php?p=actions/assets/generate-transform&transformId=10406
```

The second-site transform gives an internal server error 500

```
https://www.second-site.com/index.php?p=actions/assets/generate-transform&transformId=10406
```

My 'second-site' index.php has the following constants:

```
define('CRAFT_SITE', 'second-site');
define('CRAFT_BASE_PATH', '/home1/client-dir');
define('CRAFT_STORAGE_PATH', CRAFT_BASE_PATH.'/storage');
define('CRAFT_VENDOR_PATH', CRAFT_BASE_PATH.'/vendor');
define('CRAFT_TEMPLATES_PATH', CRAFT_BASE_PATH.'/templates');
```

I should note that **I'm using Amazon S3 to serve my assets** (using the S3 plugin). Also, the assets field is set to relate assets from the default site.

**UPDATE:** In my log file, I'm seeing the following error:

```
2020-10-01 20:25:27 [-][-][-][error][Error] Error: Call to a member function getVolume() on null in /home1/client-dir/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/AssetTransforms.php:648
Stack trace:
#0 /home1/client-dir/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/AssetTransforms.php(603): craft\services\AssetTransforms->_generateTransform(Object(craft\models\AssetTransformIndex))
#1 /home1/client-dir/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/AssetsController.php(1179): craft\services\AssetTransforms->ensureTransformUrlByIndexModel(Object(craft\models\AssetTransformIndex))
#2 [internal function]: craft\controllers\AssetsController->actionGenerateTransform(11357)
#3 /home1/client-dir/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 /home1/client-dir/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(157): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#5 /home1/client-dir/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php(178): yii\base\Controller->runAction('generate-transf...', Array)
#6 /home1/client-dir/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(528): craft\web\Controller->runAction('generate-transf...', Array)
#7 /home1/client-dir/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(291): yii\base\Module->runAction('assets/generate...', Array)
#8 /home1/client-dir/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(559): craft\web\Application->runAction('assets/generate...', Array)
#9 /home1/client-dir/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(270): craft\web\Application->_processActionRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#10 /home1/client-dir/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#11 /home1/client-dir/public_html/second-site/index.php(28): yii\base\Application->run()
#12 {main}
2020-10-01 20:25:26 [-][-][-][info][application] $_GET = [
    'p' => 'actions/assets/generate-transform'
    'transformId' => '11357'
]
```

**Craft Version:** 3.4.24  **Amazon S3 Plugin:** 1.2.8

Has anyone else experienced this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Brandon Kelly on Discord:

> If you go to the Assets index page and change the site to your second
> site. Are you able to see all the same assets there? (Specifically
> whatever ones appear to be causing this error on your second site)

They weren't listed.

> Had a feeling that would be the case. That's your problem. If you run
> `php craft resave/assets`, does that fix it?

**Yes it did!** Thanks :-)